# Get current browser timezone in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

`Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` This Javascript code I am using to get the current timezone of the browser. This works fine in both Chrome and Firefox browsers. However this code is not working in IE 11.

I also tried other option which I found `moment.tz().zoneName()`; but this also didn't work for me.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Use polyfill for IE.

Answer (score 1):

moment.tz.guess() will give you browser's timezone. It is documented [here](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/).

Comment: that method is not supported in IE 11, from their docs: "Moment Timezone uses the Internationalization API (Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone) in supported browsers to determine the user's time zone." That API doesn't work in IE 11.

Comment: @ccnokes, It uses Internationalization API in supported browsers. "On other browsers, time zone detection is rather tricky to get right, as there is little information provided by those browsers. For those, it will use Date#getTimezoneOffset and Date#toString on a handful of moments around the current year to gather as much information about the browser environment as possible. It then compares that information with all the time zone data loaded and returns the closest match. In case of ties, the time zone with the city with largest population is returned. "

Comment: I just tried "moment.tz.guess()" and it gave me correct value in IE11